# break words in fabricjs causes selection bugs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

im using [fabricjs](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) in my project with a ["Allow cutted words in a Textbox shape"](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/4513) hack. It breaks words as will, but  the last letter in the second line can not be selected.

need some help.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('thisisaextremlongwordlongenoughtowarp', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 400,
  fontSize: 24,
});
textbox.setControlsVisibility({'mb': false, 'mt': false});
canvas.add(textbox).setActiveObject(textbox);
```

press ctrl+a to select all,the last letter is missing from selection
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7tG.png)

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Da7SP/736/) from JSteunou has the same problem also

Comment: You'll have to post a specific example of your problem if you want people to be able to try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the current selection area there is an index incremented per newline to account for a return or space. Since you are breaking a word that has no space or special character in the textarea, you will be displaced. Perhaps put some form of flag on your linebreak line and do not increment for that line? You would then need to re-establish your stylemap id imagine.

Shay